# How to Sync project with gradle files

Tags: android, android-studio

why is sync project with gradle files in Android studio taking so much time?Do I require  internet connection while doing so?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read through the [How to ask a good question section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding new libraries then yes  you need to have strong internet connection to sync the gradle

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you have added some new Dependencies, then there is need for an internet connection.